# Store output of a XSLT node into XSLT variable

Tags: xslt

My XSLT v1.0 code -

```
<Test1>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/root/node1">B</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="/root/node2">S</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>NA</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>     
</Test1>
```

I want to store the output of the above node `<Test1>` into a variable. Something like this,

```
<xsl:variable name="test">
    <xsl:value-of select="??"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Use the value of this variable to compute something else or display the value,

```
<Test2>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$test"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</Test2>
```

What should I write instead of `??` to get the value of the node `<Test1>`? Or is there any other way by which I can read the output value of a node into a variable in XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want

```
<xsl:variable name="test">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/root/node1">B</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="/root/node2">S</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>NA</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then

```
<Test2>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$test"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</Test2>
```

You could use an element node as the wrapper but it does not improve things if you simply want to deal with some strings like `B` or `NA`.

Comment: I have multiple nodes like `Test1` and do not want to duplicate the code to read the value into a variable. Can you suggest something else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can store values in variables, even nodes. But at least with an XSLT 1.0 processor you end up with result tree fragments where all you can do is using `copy-of` or `value-of` on them. I am not sure how you want to use your variable, for the case you have shown I think my suggestion suffices, please edit your question with more details.